# Intercalar registros em foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Estou fazendo uma listagem de registros e estou com a seguinte dificuldade:

No meu sistema eu tenho duas tabelas e eu preciso listar os registros delas de forma intercalada.

O local da listagem é o mesmo. Só que eu não posso fazer um foreach para listar uma e depois listar os registros da outra.

Vez ou outra (de forma randômica) eu vou ter que exibir um registro da tabela 2 no meio da listagem da tabela 1.

Imagine um sistema que vai imprimindo anúncios no meio dos registros reais. É mais ou menos isso que eu preciso fazer.

Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Pode postar o que você ja tentou fazer?

Comment: Eu estou completamente sem ideias de como fazer isso. Eu tenho só os foreachs para cada tabela =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar tudo num array e usar a função suffle para misturar o conteúdo.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$registos = array("noticia1","noticia2", "noticia3");
$anuncios = array("anuncio1", "anuncio2", "anuncio3");

$lista = array_merge($registos, $anuncios);

shuffle($lista);

foreach ($lista as $linha){
    echo "$linha\n";
}

?>
```

Veja o código funcionando no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/658A4a)

Ou seja, primeiro usa a função [array_merge](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) que permite fundir dois arrays.
Depois para misturar os conteúdos usa a função [suffle](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: Com esta dica eu já estou quase lá!!!

Um outro problema que surgiu é o seguinte:
Eu estou usando duas tabelas diferente do banco de dados. E elas possuem quantidade de campos diferentes. E alguns nomes de campos destas tabelas coincidem.

Eu consigo extrair os dados iterando um foreach dentro de outro foreach. Mas como eu identifico cada campo? Por exemplo: como eu sei que o valor retornado é uma imagem?

Eu não estou conseguindo utilizar $array[nome_campo].

Comment: Eu tava vacilando. Acabou que fiz exatamente o que você sugeriu e deu certinho =D

Muito obrigado!!!